# Angular http request not able to map correction

Tags: angular

I am using this method to fetch data. i am unable to get the mapping correct.

I am getting the following logged in the console.

> getEmployees:
>   {"_body":"[{\"employeeId\":1,\"employeeNum\":\"001\",\"employedDate\":\"2011-01-01T00:00:00\",\"terminatedDate\":null},{\"employeeId\":2,\"employeeNum\":\"002\",\"employedDate\":\"2012-02-01T00:00:00\",\"terminatedDate\":\"2016-02-01T00:00:00\"},{\"employeeId\":3,\"employeeNum\":\"003\",\"employedDate\":\"2013-03-01T00:00:00\",\"terminatedDate\":\"2016-10-01T00:00:00\"}]","status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"content-type":["application/json;
>   charset=utf-8"]},"type":2,"url":"http://localhost:8948/api/employees"}

When I move .do line after the .map i get getEmployees: undefined.

```
getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
        this.loggerService.log(`Getting Employees`);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'get' });
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
        .do(data => console.log('getEmployees: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .map(response => response.json().data as IEmployee[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

My IEmployee is defined as such

```
export interface IEmployee {
    employeeId: number;
    employeeNum: string;
    employedDate: string;
    terminatedDate : string;
}
```

What am i doing incorrect. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not passing `options` into your invocation of `get`.

Comment: HI thanks for your reply.  did try  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl,options) but got the same response.

Comment: For one thing, your response doesn't have a `data` property so you will end up with `undefined` if you access it. It is unclear what your actual problem is or what behavior you expect. `return this.http.get(this.baseUrl).do(console.log).map(r => r.json());` should be sufficient. Do not pass an unbound method as a callback: `.catch(this.handleError);` is wrong and will always be wrong unless `handleError` is an `=>` property and not a method.

Comment: You mean you move this line `.do(data => console.log('getEmployees: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))`after the `.map`?

Comment: It does not matter. `do` does not project the Observable.

Comment: Yes that is what i mean

Comment: Your problem is accessing `.data` not calling `.do`

Comment: Then instead of `.do(data => console.log('getEmployees: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))`write `.do(console.log)`. After the `.map``

Comment: There is no property named `data` on the value returned by `response.json()`. That is why the message changes if project the observable before logging it.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is now working.